# What is meant by "Prince in Exile"?

Tags: cinema

I saw the tag *Prince In Exile* in a [movie poster](https://southreel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Agnathavasi-Teaser-Release-Date-Posternew-songsAgnathavasi-TeaserAgnathavasi-trailerAgnathavasi-movie-stillsAgnathavasi-Gaali-Vaaluga-songAgnathavasi-2nd-songAgnathavasi-movie-songsAgnathavasi-1st-song.jpg). But I still don't get its meaning.

[image: prince in exile]

Comment: It means what the individual words mean. A prince is a male member of the royal family who isn't the king, probably one who is in line of succession to the throne. "In exile" means not allowed to go to his home country.

Comment: That's not a *tag*. It's the English translation of the title of the Indian Telugu-language movie [*Agnyaathavaasi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnyaathavaasi).

Answer (score 1):

> To be in exile means to be away from one's home (i.e. city, state, or country), while either being explicitly refused permission to return or being threatened with imprisonment or death upon return. It can be a form of punishment and solitude.

So, taking the above-mentioned into consideration, I think that the movie simply tells a story about a prince who's away from his kingdom and home.